# Office Fluent UI / DatePicker - onSelectDate does not send event as parameter

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui

I use the Datapicker component:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/datepicker

In one form i use multiple DatePicker components like startDate, endDate, etc.

I call the DatePicker components like this:

```
 <DatePicker
            label="Start date"
            id="dateFrom"
            name="dateFrom"
            onSelectDate={props.onChangeDatePicker}
            value={new Date(props.entity.datumFrom)}
          />
```

The documentation says that onSelectData callback function only gives a selected date as a parameter.

**onSelectDate - (date: Date | null | undefined) => void**

*There is not event returned that would help me know which of the following datepickers was selected.*

This functionality exists for example on the TextField component that has the method onChange:

**onChange-
(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, newValue?: string) => void**

When i have the event i can call **event.target.name** and **event.target.value** to get the needed info.

Is there a way to get the event, or some other object so i can know which datepicker component was called?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  handleDateSelection = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
}

<DatePicker
        label="Start date"
        id="dateFrom"
        name="dateFrom"
        onSelectDate={this.handleDateSelection}
        value={new Date(props.entity.datumFrom)}
      />
```

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKQEX.png)